# I'm trying to move the links in navigation bar to right by 160px but i can't do that

Tags: html, css, width, navigationbar

Here is the css is using

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
    #cssmenu {
    background: #f96e5b;
    width: auto;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: 160px;
    zoom: 1;
    }
    #cssmenu ul:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }
#cssmenu.align-right ul li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s;
  -moz-transition: color .25s;
  -ms-transition: color .25s;
  -o-transition: color .25s;
  transition: color .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: .5;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #333333;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width .25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu.align-right li:last-child > a:after {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:first-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #cssmenu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fb998c;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li.last > a,
  #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a {
    border: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

The html i'm using is as belows

```
    <div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

When i use this code my site the navigation bar applys to full width and link on the navigation bar are at left end. I want to move the link on navigation bar 160px right side.

My site http://logansdroids.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-allign` doesn't takes values is `px`s.

Use this:

```
  #cssmenu > ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-left: 160px;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Worked fine in my blog thank you, if i want to make the navigation bar center(not full width) without extending it left and right. If you need example check this blog's navigation bar below the main navigation bar http://www.shoutmeloud.com

Comment: Add `containernbt` to you `NewContainer section` element. It's working like that coz its not having any width and parent container is giving it `100%` width by default.